# Libgdx text in place rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

In libgdx is there any way to rotate a text around itself?

Actually i need to keep the text always aligned horizontally without any rotation while the `SpriteBatch` of the text and the background can be translated/rotated by user's gesture.

(I am using `BitmapFont` and `SpriteBatch` to draw the texts.)

```
  font.draw(batch, text, (wayCentroid.x - text.length() / 2) / batch.getTransformMatrix().getScaleX(), (wayCentroid.y + 3) / batch.getTransformMatrix().getScaleY());
```

Comment: Maybe use `Stage` and `Label` instead? Actors can pretty easily be rotated.

Comment: @noone A stage is not mandatory to draw a label. Just creating a label and positioning it in the world should be enough. Then just `myLabel.rotateBy` should rotate the text and draw it by `myLabel.draw(worldBatch, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by messing with the batch matrix. But `noone` is right about using `Label` to rotate text.

If you want X to be rotated and Y to stay in place then I think you should just rotate X and leave Y instead of rotating the `SpriteBatch` and rotate Y backwards.

Anyway if you know the angle of your rotation then something like this should do the trick:

```
Label myLabel = new Label("My Text", skin);
myLabel.setPosition(worldPosX, worldPosY);
myLabel.setRotation(-angleInDegrees);
myLabel.draw(worldBatch, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I would also recommend you to use the Scene2D Label class to handle your text (*to be honest I would recommend you to use Scene2D at all because it will make easier all rotation/move/scale actions you would like to act on your actors*) the second option is to **create the second camera and viewport** and use it to render the text.

```
    //in the show() method
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,camera);
    viewport.apply();

    camera2 = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport2 = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,camera2);
    viewport2.apply();

    ... //setting camera positions etc

    camera.rotate(50); //now you are rotating first camera

    ...

    //in the render() method
    ...

    camera.update();
    camera2.update();

    batch.begin();

    //rendering rotated elements
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);        
    batch.draw(someRotatedSprite, sprite_x, sprite_y);

    ...

    //now rendering not rotated ones
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera2.combined);        
    font.draw(batch, "Some text here", text_x, text_y); //the text should has center in the center of the camera!!

    ...

    batch.end();
```